# Sorting Alphabetically and by Cell Color

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to sort multiple lists Alphabetically and by Cell Color but within a certain range (so it doesn't take too long). Basically the VBA is suppose to select for example column B rows 3-88, sort by alphabet, then sort by color. Then move to next column C3:C88, etc, until column NY.

When I try it, I get Run-time error 1004: Mathod "Range" of object '_Global' failed.

This is my VBA:

```
Sub SortAlphaColor()
' Sorts rows within a list from A-Z
' Run Clean all first to avoid sorting blanks
' Set maximum range to avoid sorting too many rows

    Dim rngFirstRow As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngFirstRow = ws.Range("B3:NY3")
    For Each rng In rngFirstRow
        With ws.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=rng, Order:=xlAscending
            'assuming there are no blank cells..
            .SetRange ws.Range(rng, rng.Range("B88").End(xlUp))
                'VBA from second module
                .SortFields.Add(Range(rng), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206) <- this line is highlighted in debug
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Apply
        End With
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your problem is somewhere here: `Range(rng)` I think. Change it to simply `rng`...

Comment: Not sure what happened but when I ran it, it moved row 89 to row 3 :/

Comment: isn't it just sorting as you expect?... run you procedure initially with F8 key and check for the beginning of iteration if it's working correct. I think final result of you sub is sorting result of whole range based on NY3 cell...

Comment: `rng.Range("B88")` are you sure you want this? If rng=B3 then `rng.Range("B88")`=C90 ie. when using `Range` on anything other then a worksheet, the range is always relative. Maybe you want something like `rng.Resize(86, 1)`.  Also, you don't need `.SortFields.Add(Range(rng),...`: since rng is already a range object you can just use rng by itself  `.SortFields.Add(rng,...`

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure. I just need to make sure it's sorting between row 3 and 88. Before it used to do the entire column and caused my sheet to crash, so now i'm just trying to make sure it's not going past what it needs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Sub SortAlphaColor()

    Dim rngFirstRow As Range
    Dim rng As Range, rngSort As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngFirstRow = ws.Range("B3:NY3")
    For Each rng In rngFirstRow.Cells
        With ws.Sort

            Set rngSort = rng.Resize(86, 1) 'to row 88

            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SortFields.Add(rng, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                            SortOnValue.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
            .SetRange rngSort
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply

        End With
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: How can this translate to C#? Thanks

Comment: How can I tie my shoes?

Comment: :) It was a question because I am trying to do the same thing and not able to succeed. I don't have the `interop` dll embedded so I can find `Color` after `SortOnValue`. That's where I am stuck.

Comment: I'm not that up on C# and interop, so you might need to post a separate question on this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't see `.Color` after `SortOnValue` as an option. Any idea why?

Comment: You don't see it *where* ?

Comment: What version of Excel?  I think you need at least 2010   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840676(v=office.14).aspx