# Using VBA to sort highlighted cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort the cells by whether they are highlighted or not. If they are I am looking for those rows to be at the top.

Have tried some code from another question but can't figure it out.

```
'sort highlighted and alphabetical
Sub SortColor()

    Dim rngFirstRow As Range
    Dim rng As Range, rngSort As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = Sheets("modified_report")
    Set rngFirstRow = ws.Range("K2:M2")
    For Each rng In rngFirstRow.Cells
        With ws.Sort

            Set rngSort = rng.Resize(150, 1)

            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add(rng, xlSortOnCellColor, xlDescending, , xlSortNormal). _
                            SortOnValue.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
            .SetRange rngSort
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply

        End With
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If there are highlighted cells in columns K:M, I was those row at the top.

I can't get the whole row to move to the top. This code seems to just move those cells and therefore messes with the rest of the row.

Comment: Why does `rngFirstRow` have two rows? That means you do the sort twice on each column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting Alphabetically and by Cell Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530785/sorting-alphabetically-and-by-cell-color)

Comment: I still can't figure this one out, any help?